# Converting Strings to Dates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Have a column in a DataFrame that are strings of dates. For example, '09/10/11' is September 10, 2011. I would like to convert the strings to dates, but receive an error when using pandas.to_datetime. The following line receives the error: "ValueError: time data '09/10/11' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)".

```
pd.to_datetime(df.PERIOD, format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: maybe you wanted `%y`?

Comment: alternatively to `format='%m/%d/%y'` (which will work), you may try to omit it at all

Comment: ok, follow up questions: Why does 'y' work over 'Y', all previous examples I've seen use 'Y'?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this as the documentation isn't explicit, but I believe that the format argument is using the same rules as datetime in the standard library.  Basically, %y is a two digit year while %Y is a four digit year.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior